# Concatenate in Meteor Template Tags

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, demeteorizer

I have a list of numbers in my Meteor Template which I am iterating to print the attributes of the object. I have an object named `choices_object` which will have number of choices depending upon the situation. 
objects fields will be `choice_1` `choice_2` `choice_3` and so on.
I have the same number of values in an array as object fields.

```
values=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

In my template I have to concatenate the name of objects fields with this number to complete the names of fields.

```
<template name="choices_template">
    {{#with choices_object}}
        {{#each values}}
            {{choice_ .}}    <!-- it should be {{choice_1}} and so on depends on the value of dot.
        {{/each}}
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Is it possible to concatenate a variable name as i am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a proper json for your data and then iterate directly through the values. For example:

```
Template.choices.choices = function() {
  var array = [];
  _.each(choices, function(choice, idx) {
    array.push({
      value: choice,
      idx: idx,
    });
  });
  return array;
};
```

```
{{#each choices}}
  {{value}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanx for reply @Hubert OG. It solves half of my problem, thanx.

Comment: But can you please suggest me how can i Iterate over the fields of object in meteor template without knowing the fields of object

Comment: It's not directly possible - again, you'd need to preprocess it. For example, convert the object with all its fields to an array: `_.map(object, function(val, key) {return {key: key, val: val};})`.